# How to construct Twilio sms message in controller when using MessageResource?

Tags: c#, twilio, visual-studio-2017

I am attempting to recreate behavior that is exhibited by **CallResource/CreateCallOptions** in that a **CallOptions.Url** is used to fetch the TwiML necessary to place the call. This effectively allows me to construct the outgoing call via the controller. I would like to have this option for SMS messages also.

I am aware that I can use a url for **StatusCallBack** that does get called, but I am unable to construct and send a message from this controller action. No matter how I arrange it so far, only the message from **MessageResource.Create** gets sent.

Is there a way to accomplish this built into the Twilio sdk that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You cannot initiate an SMS directly using TwiML in a controller, for that you need to [use the REST API to send messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages).

When you set a URL as a handler for incoming messages to your Twilio number you can use that URL to respond to those incoming messages though.

You can hook up a controller to receive these incoming webhooks and respond with a `MessagingResponse` to create TwiML. Most notably, you can use [`<Message>` to respond to an SMS with an SMS in reply](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message).

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Well, it is the answer - though it doesn't help with the problem that I had initially. I was trying to have it be part of the same session. No worries though, I definitely understand why it is done this way and I have other ways to solve the problem.